# "SELECT LAG(id) FROM cb_cat WHERE id=450";

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I want to return the previous row based on the current id number.
All id numbers are UNIQUE, but are NOT (necessarily) SEQUENTIAL.

```
SELECT LAG(id) FROM cb_cat WHERE id=450;
```

I thought this query should work.

If possible, I would like to return * from the previous row before the current id.
I do not know which id number that is, but it is smaller than the current id number, e.g. 450. It could be 449 or even 1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've corrected my answer, feel free to give it a try and ask any questions that may come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window functions work on the result after the `WHERE` clause is applied. Since `id` is unique and you ask for exactly one `id`, that result has a maximum of one row. There just isn't any previous row whatsoever.

Further more relational tables represent relations which are a special form of (multi) sets. And (multi) sets aren't ordered. Unless there's an explicit `ORDER BY`, the order the tuples of a result are returned in is to be considered random. Window functions depending on an order therefore also need an `ORDER BY` specified in the `OVER` clause, unless they just should pick some random row. You didn't specify what defines your order, I assume it's the `id` in the following.

Using `lag()` you'd have to select all rows in a derived table where you apply the `lag()` and then go for the row with the `id` of `450` in the outer `SELECT`.

```
SELECT l
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    lag(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) l
                    FROM cb_cat) x
       WHERE id = 450;
```

This can be optimized a little. Since `id` defines the order, we actually only need to look at the records with an `id` lower than or equal to `450` in the inner `SELECT`. (I have doubts the optimizer would figure this out by itself. But maybe I'm underestimating its capabilities.)

```
SELECT l
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    lag(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) l
                    FROM cb_cat
                    WHERE id <= 450) x
       WHERE id = 450;
```

But if we think of it, what we actually want is the the largest `id` that is less than `450`. `lag()` isn't the best tool to get this, `LIMIT` is. We get all `id`s less than `450`, order them in descending order and pick the first one of that ordered result.

```
SELECT id
       FROM cb_cat
       WHERE id < 450
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Nice. You can improve the last query. No need for `DISTINCT ON`, just add `LIMIT 1` at the end. `SELECT * FROM cb_cat WHERE id < 450 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Thanks for the pointer. True, `LIMIT` is simpler here, there aren't any groups (well, except one large one...).

Comment: Thank you! I am able to even use SELECT * and it will return the whole previous row.
By swapping the `<` for `>` and changing the sort order to `ASC` I am able to get the next row too:
`SELECT * FROM cb_cat WHERE id > 450 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: I wonder which query is less resource heavy? I have 1 database which has over 70.000 records. Does it first select ALL rows with id less than 450 and then limits the return? Or does it limit the selection first to only 1? :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an `OVER` and `ORDER BY` clause to your lag function so it knows how to order the records to select the previous one. Also you can specify how many rows back to look (in this case one row back).

For example: `SELECT LAG(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id)  FROM cb_cat WHERE id=450`

Using this you can either apply the `LAG()` function to every column you want to get the previous value of, or you can use a CTE or subquery to get just the ID of the previous row and then filter on it like so:

```
WITH PreviousRowId AS 
(
    SELECT LAG(id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS PreviousRowId, id AS CurrentRowId
    FROM cb_cat
)

SELECT C.*
FROM cb_cat AS C
INNER JOIN PreviousRowId AS P
    ON C.id = P.PreviousRowId
WHERE P.CurrentRowId = 450
```

There's good examples and more information on the `LAG()` function [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I don't follow what column UNIQUENESS has to do with anything, but your comment did make me realize I misplaced my WHERE predicate. I've fixed my answer and this should produce what OP is looking for.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Gotcha, yes, thanks for pointing that out. Slip of the predicate. :)